# Tailwind v3.1 and above, bg-primary color not overriding bg-white

Tags: tailwind-css

After upgrading to v3.1 of tailwind (from 3.0), the following code has stopped working

```
<div className={classNames('... bg-white...', {'bg-primary': someCondition})} />
```

Playing around with Tailwind sandbox, I see that this is happening too.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/

Go to the config:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: 'blue',
        'new-primary': 'green',
      }
      // ...
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

in html:

```
<div class="relative flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-center items-center overflow-hidden bg-gray-50 py-6 sm:py-12">
  <div class='w-16 h-16 bg-white border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-full bg-primary'/>
</div>
```

Note that the circle is still white. If you change **bg-primary** to **bg-new-primary**, you will see the circle is green. If you remove **bg-white** from **bg-white bg-primary** the circle will be blue.

Also, if you go to the config and add in theme.colors = {}, it will work.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  theme: {
    colors: {},
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: 'blue',
        'new-primary': 'green',
      }
      // ...
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I don't want to go through my code base and change bg-primary (or text-primary, ...) to some other variable name if I don't have to. So why is Tailwind behaving like this? v3.0 and earlier doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider only having one instance of a utility class per property per variant. In your case, when `someCondition` is truthy, both `bg-white` and `bg-primary` apply to the `<div>` element, causing the conflict. The class that applies is the one that appears *later* in the **CSS, not the HTML**.

Consider refactoring like so:

```
<div className={classNames('…', {'bg-primary': someCondition, 'bg-white': !someCondition })} />
```